# Replace all HTML tags with PHP

Tags: php, html, regex

I am having a problem some regular expression.
I am using the following regular expression to obtain text between html tags.

```
preg_replace("/<.*>/ix", " ", $input_lines);
```

This expression works well with

```
<a href="some.html">Somelink
```

output is
Somelink

But it doesn't work with

```
  <a href="some.html">Somelink</a>
```

it shows a blank output.

My Actual input is like this

```
<a href="some.html">Somelink</a><anytag>Somelink</anytag>
```

And Desired output is

```
Somelink Somelink
```

all Tags whether starting or ending tag gets replaced by spaces.

And a Small question:

Comment: Why are you trying to replicate [`strip_tags`](http://php.net/strip_tags) ?

Comment: I want single space between words :|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understood your problem , you may use this method `strip_tags`

see [this link](http://php.net/strip_tags)
 Perhaps it helps you

Comment: I used and it produces output as "SomelinkSomelink"

Answer (score 1):

In your regex `.*` means before the last `>`

So it should be `.*?`

More safely, it will be `[^>]*`

Comment: "More safely"... until I inject a `>` into an attribute value.

Comment: I don't know much about html. If I can put `>` inside any attributes, then `[^>]*` should not be used.

Answer (score 0):

Try `strip_tags` function.

For replacing, try this

`$result = preg_replace('/[ ]{2,}/imx', ' ', $subject);`